# Can't use dotnet core on Nano Server (TP5)

Tags: powershell, asp.net, dotnet-framework, windows-nano-server

I was trying to follow all the instructions from the next tutorial: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/nano-server.html#id9 , but there has occured one problem...

Seems to be, dotnet core wasn't installed successfully, because if to run any appropriate command, like: `dotnet new`, `dotnet restore` I shall get the next error (on Nano server):

> [192.168.10.8]: PS C:\Temp> dotnet publish dotnet : Did you mean to
>   run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Did you mean to...tnet SDK from: :String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

I've installed dotnet core via next Power-Shell script: http://pastebin.com/nwaLcQam

So, I'm not able to run the compiled ASP.NET Web API on Nano Server. What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should publish your application in your development environment and deploy the published version to the nano server